# The distance of closest approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

A point charge $+q$ is projected from a point $A$ towards an infinitely long line changes having linear charge density $\lambda$ with kinetic energy $k_0$.The distance of closest approach will be

[image]

Since no external force is applied 
$$\Delta U=-\Delta K$$
$$q dV =\Delta K$$
$$dV=\int_{r+a}^r \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0r}{dr}$$
$$\ln(\frac{r}{a}+1)=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0k_0}{\lambda q}$$
$$r=a(1-e^{\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0k_0}{\lambda q}})$$

What did I do wrong? My answer is not matching with options.

Comment: What is the specific physics concept you are having trouble with? This is not a check-your-work site.

Comment: @heather Is my second equation is correct

Comment: Your second equation is ... odd.   It's taking you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Coulombic force]

An infinitesimal element $dx$ carries a charge of:
$$dq=\lambda dx$$

Which exerts a force $dF$ on the charge $q$, acc. Coulomb:
$$dF=\frac{k_eq\lambda}{r^2}dx$$

We're only interested in the y component of the force, $dF_y$:
$$dF_y=dF\cos\theta=\frac{a}{r}dF$$
With $r^2=x^2+a^2$ we get:

$$dF_y=\frac{k_eq\lambda}{r^2}\frac{a}{r}dx=ak_eq\lambda\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$$
To obtain the total force $F_y$ we integrate from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$:
$$F_y=ak_eq\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$F_y=ak_eq\lambda\Bigg[\frac{x}{a^2\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\Bigg]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$$
Using limit theory, we find:
$$F_y=\frac{2k_eq\lambda}{a}$$

Now work needs to be done *against* $F_y$, so that the kinetic energy becomes $0$:

$$-\int_a^yF_ydy=K_0$$
$$-2k_eq\lambda\int_a^y\frac{dy}{y}=K_0$$
$$\ln\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)=-\frac{K_0}{2k_eq\lambda}$$
$$\Large{y=ae^{-\frac{K_0}{2k_eq\lambda}}}$$

At this distance, the charge $q$ has no more kinetic energy.

Comment: What wrong with my method

Comment: For one, the expression $dV=\int_{r+a}^a \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln{r}}$ is wrong: the integral has no integrant! You don't seem to have an expression for the repulsive force between the line charge and $q$.

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to homework-like questions.  Our policy on this can be found [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/5739) which includes:  “If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.”  Please consider deleting this answer yourself.  Also, this answer seems unnecessarily complex, and I think it's even wrong.

Comment: Correction: the final answer is correct.  (I was looking for $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$).   But the answer is excessively long, and see above concerning answers to homework questions.

Comment: @garyp: in what way is it *"excessively long"*? It's a simple step-by-step derivation of the repulsive force between line charge and point charge, which is lacking in OP's work. W/o it the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: Hard to answer you without answering the question.  Let's try this: if you read the OP, you will see that he knows the equation for the potential due to a line of charge ...

Answer (score 1):

The [potential difference between two points at distances $r$ and $a$ from an infinitely long line of uniform positive charge](https://www.miniphysics.com/uy1-electric-potential-of-an-infinite-line-charge.html) is
$$\Delta V = V(r)-V(a) = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}ln(\frac{a}{r})$$

Using $a$ as the distance to the line charge from the point of projection A, and equating KE lost to the PE gained, the distance of closest approach $r$ is given by
$$k_0= q\Delta V=q\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}ln(\frac{a}{r})$$
$$C=\frac{2\pi\epsilon_0 k_0}{q\lambda}=ln(\frac{a}{r})$$
$$r=a e^{-C}$$.

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that you started at a distance $r+a$ and finished at a distance $a$ whereas it should be from distance $a$ to distance $r$.

Another error is here $$dV=\int_{r+a}^a \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln{r}}$$

as $V(r) = -\dfrac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln{r}}$ there is no integration to be done.
All you need to do is to find $V(r) - V(a) = -\dfrac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln{r}} - \left (-\dfrac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0}{\ln{a}} \right )$.

---

If you place a Gaussian cylinder of length $l$ and radius $r$ symmetrically around a length $l$ of the line charge and apply Gauss's law you get

$$2 \pi r l E= \dfrac {\lambda l}{\epsilon_o} \Rightarrow E=\dfrac{\lambda }{2 \pi \epsilon_o r}$$

for the electric field at a distance $r$ from the line of charge.

The since $V(r) - V(a) = - \int_a^r  qE\; dr$ you get that $$V(r) - V(a) = \dfrac {\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_o}\ln \left ( \dfrac{a}{r} \right)$$

So all that you need to do is use the conservation of energy:

$$qV(a) + k_o = qV(r) + 0 $$ with the charge $q$ having zero kinetic energy when $r$ away from the line of charge.

So finally you can find $r$.